# Reading a Python file from Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to work with a file

[image]

But when I try to access this file, I get an error: ***No such file or directory***

[image]

[image]

Can you tell me how to access files in hdfs correctly?

UPD:

The author of the answer directed me in the right direction.
As a result, this is how I execute the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#import pandas as pd
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
   print('Hello, ' + line)

# this is hello.py
```

And Scala application:

```
spark.sparkContext.addFile(getClass.getResource("hello.py").getPath, true)
val test = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List("Body!")).repartition(1)

val piped = test.pipe(SparkFiles.get("./hello.py"))

val c = piped.collect()
c.foreach(println)
```

Output: Hello, Body!

Now I have to think about whether, as a cluster user, I can install pandas on workers.

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with HDFS. `Scala.io.fromFile` exclusively refers to the local filesystem. All you're doing is printing a URI, never actually downloading any files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try directly referencing the external file rather than attempting to download it to your Spark driver just to upload it again

```
spark.sparkContext.addFile(s"hdfs://$srcPy")
```